# Highcharts export chart new window/tab

Tags: image, highcharts, export

I tried the demo on iPad2. It still opens in same window with the URL export.highcharts.com. How can we open/save the image in new tab/window on iPad2?

Been trying to save/open Highchart images in a new tab.

Reference Link:

[How to get the exported image without moving from the current window when using mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837282/how-to-get-the-exported-image-without-moving-from-the-current-window-when-using)

Please advice.

Comment: But what is wrong with the related topic?

Comment: Just try that solution: http://jsfiddle.net/FH6rx/

Comment: Thanks, Paweł Fus.  Your solution works.  You should have posted it as answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post Paweł's answer, for reference.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }],
        
        exporting: {
            formAttributes: {
                target: '_blank'
            }
        }
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; margin-top: 1em"></div>
```

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

```
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }],

    exporting: {
        formAttributes: {
            target: '_blank'
        }
    }

});
```

});