# How to open chart in new tab?

Tags: highcharts

I am using highchart and my idea is when I click to the button `Export Chart in New Tab`, a new tab should be opened and the same chart will be drawn again there. Are there any available functions in highchart that allow me to do this? or what I am thinking is bring all data now to the new tab and draw the new chart there. But I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone help me?

[My jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtyLtd71/)

Comment: A new tab on the web page or a new browser window?

Comment: yes new tab on the web page

Comment: What are you using for your tab framework? There are many ways to do this but they are different for each framework.

Comment: sorry I dont really get it. I mean for example now I have a chart in one tab of my Chrome, then when I click to the button, a new tab will open and display the same chart

Comment: A new Chrome tab or a tab in the webpage itself?

Comment: If it is just a new browser tab try solution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889647/highcharts-export-chart-new-window-tab

Comment: oh, thank you wergeld

Comment: @Sonn If you problem is not resolved, please provide more info. If it is, then you could post an answer with a solution that worked for you.

Comment: @KacperMadej hi Kacper, I just updated my solution below

Answer (score 1):

I found one way to solve the problem although I think it not the best solution. I will create a new html file with new div chart container there. And when the user click to the open chart in the new tab, I will navigate and send all parameters need for drawing the chart: like data, chart type,... to this new html file, and then I will call a new draw chart function from highchart in order to draw the chart there